# Querying Azure Logs

Tags: ilogger, appinsights

I am logging some predefined text and the actual response from my service provider in case of some error. So, the **Message** property of the log contains some text and the actual json response from client.

I want to query and prepare a list of errors logged in traces. My log example is given below

```
Calling partner failed: GetCarVariants by registration Number failed. Status: InternalServerError. Content: {"general":{"globalTransactionID":"guid"},"errorDetails":{"explanation":"TBD","proposedHttpError":403,"showToCustomer":false,"errorCode":"E60001","errorText":"Error description","title":"WSAVM-A1"}}
```

For example i need a list given below

errorCode |  errorText

EG0061    |  Error 1

EG0062    |  Error 2